# Excel - search for a cell containing those values alone

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know if there's a way to search cells in Excel for a string, that contain only that string i.e if i were searching for "egor," avoid highlighting cells that might have "category" in them?

Thanks

Comment: Yes there is. Specify the `LookAt` argument of `Find` to be `xlWhole`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a parameter for the `Range.Find` method called `LookAt` which determines if the function searches partial or whole cells.

```
Set C = MyRange.Find(SomeText, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for exact strings by using VLoolUp function, you have the documentation here:

[VlookUp](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

If the string is found it will return the found value, if it's not found it will return a N/A error.

Hope it helps.